# Select data from two MongoDB tables and update the results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We have the following problem

Given are the tables and fields

- Offer

  - OfferId
  - State
- Article

  - OfferId
  - ArticleId
  - NetPrice
  - GrossPrice
  - VatRate

**Example-data:**

Offer-Collection

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "State": "INITIAL",
    "_class": "com.example.dto.OfferData"
}
{
    "_id": "2",
    "State": "COMPLETED",
    "_class": "com.example.dto.OfferData"
}
```

Article-Collection

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "a"
    },
    "Description": "asdf",
    "NetPrice": "100",
    "GrossPrice": "116",
    "VatRate": "16",
    "OfferId": "1",
    "_class": "com.example.dto.Article"
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "b"
    },
    "Description": "my description",
    "NetPrice": "100",
    "GrossPrice": "119",
    "VatRate": "19",
    "OfferId": "1",
    "_class": "com.example.dto.Article"
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "c"
    },
    "Description": "my description",
    "NetPrice": "100",
    "GrossPrice": "116",
    "VatRate": "16",
    "OfferId": "2",
    "_class": "com.example.dto.Article"
}
```

Now we have to update all articles belonging to an offer with the state "initial" in the following way: if the VatRate is equal to 16 than it must be updated to 19 AND the GrossPrice must be recalculated from the existing NetPrice.

**The result should be:** the article with _id = "a" and VatRate = 16 for OfferId = 1 (State = INITIAL) should have VatRate = 19 and GrossPrice = 119. The fields should be updated and persisted in the original MongoDB collection.

Can we do this only with Mongo-shell? Our Version is 3.6.

**Our tries:**
We have played around with .aggregate, $lookup, $match and $project but without much luck. It's the first time we are using the Mongo-shell.

```
db.getCollection("Offers").aggregate([{
        $lookup:{
            from:"Articles",
            localField:"OfferId",
            foreignField:"OfferId",
            as:"selected-articles"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { "state": { "$eq": "INITIAL" } }
    },
    {
        $project: { "articles": 1 }
    }
]).forEach(...?)
```

Comment: do you want to update query or want to do aggregation query to result this? can you add your tries in your question.

Comment: i have edited my question a little bit - i don't know what is the difference between an update and an aggergate query

Answer (score 1):

- `$match` your `State` condition
- `$lookup` with `Articles` collection
- `$map` to iterate loop of `selected-articles` array, check condition using `$cond` if `VatRate` is "16" then updated to 19 and recalculate `GrossPrice` as per `NetPrice` using `$multiply` before it convert NetPrice to integer because its in string type, back to merge objects with current objects using `$mergeObjects`

```
db.getCollection("Offers").aggregate([
  { $match: { State: { $eq: "INITIAL" } } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Articles",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "OfferId",
      as: "selected-articles"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "selected-articles": {
        $map: {
          input: "$selected-articles",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ["$$this.VatRate", "16"] },
                  {
                    VatRate: 19,
                    GrossPrice: {
                      $multiply: [{ $toInt: "$$this.NetPrice" }, 19]
                    }
                  },
                  {}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8-0lZzC-WLt)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The query runs without an error but it seems to do nothing to our data: VatRate and GrossPrice remain unchanged after executing the script.

Comment: you mean in result? and can you please post some sample documents for both collections.

Comment: I have attached some example data. The fields should be updated and persisted in the original MongoDB collection.

Comment: updated the answer and add playground link as well.

Comment: Your playground links works but on our local mongo shell we are getting the error "Unrecognized expression '$toInt'", "code": 168, "codeName": "InvalidPipelineOperator"}

Comment: Might be your mingodb version is below 4.0, $toInt only support form 4.0 version, i don't think there are any other good option to convert stirng to int below 4.0 versoin, if you change your that numeric prices and fields to integer in collection then you don't need to use that operators, or you can update your mongodb 4.0 or more.

Comment: You are right, our mongodb version is 3.6. It sounds that we are out of luck with it?

Comment: Yes, 2 options, first is upgrade mongodb version, or second update all fields that have string type to integer.